# Modular Inverse higher than -1

Tags: math, cryptography, inverse, wolframalpha, modular-arithmetic

Im trying to solve 2^(-5) mod 19. How to do this using EEA? I tried for like 1h and cant get the result.

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming question.  But `2^(-5)=(2^(-1))^5=(2^5)^(-1)`.  The usual rules for exponents still work in other groups.

Comment: [32^(-5) mod 19](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=what+is+the+inverse+of+32+mod+19)